# How do I make my website look the same at every screen while using padding to position stuff?

Tags: html, css, position

I'm creating a website with a grid.  I made the site's navbar (without actual links) and used the grid. Now I want to position the stuff in the different div's.

I have been told that I should use padding to do this, so I did. It worked fine until I checked it on a second monitor with a different screen size. Suddenly things drop of the screen or show up on the next line. When I didn't use padding this never happened.

How can I position objects inside a `div` without losing the advantages of using a grid system?

```css
.col-1 {width: 8.33%;}
.col-2 {width: 16.66%;}
.col-3 {width: 24.99%;}
.col-4 {width: 33.32%;}
.col-5 {width: 41.65%;}
.col-6 {width: 49.98%;}
.col-7 {width: 58.31%;}
.col-8 {width: 66.64%;}
.col-9 {width: 74.97%;}
.col-10 {width: 83.30%;}
.col-11 {width: 91.63%;}
.col-12 {width: 100%;}


* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: Montserrat;
}

[class*="col-"] {
    float: left;
}

.row:after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.navbar {
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #f27405;
    color: white;
}

.stripemenu {
    padding-left: 1%;
    position: relative;
}

.menupos {
    padding-top: 7%;
}

.space {
    padding-top: 9px;
}

.icon {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 4px;
}

.iconpos {
    padding-left: 45%;
    position: relative;
}

.share {
    padding-left: 150px;
    padding-top: 6px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Grid.css">

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row navbar col-12">
      <div class="col-1 stripemenu">
        <img src="Menu.png">
      </div>
      <div class="col-1 space">Space</div>
      <div class="col-9 icon">
        <img src="icon.png">
      </div>
      <div class="col-1 share">
        <img src="share.png">
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--Ending of first row div -->

  </div>
  <!--Ending of container div -->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Padding is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: Okay thanks. But can you tell me what I should do in this perticular case?

Comment: @WaldodePree Did you try using `px` instead of `%`?

Comment: instead of using a grid you can look into [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) is a cleaner way and is responsive right from the shelf.

Answer (score 0):

I revised your CSS code and now the navigation-bar's elements don't change the positions. I suggest to use `min-width` for the columns as everything collapse when window is resized.

```
.col-1 {width: 8.33%;}
.col-2 {width: 16.66%;}
.col-3 {width: 24.99%;}
.col-4 {width: 33.32%;}
.col-5 {width: 41.65%;}
.col-6 {width: 49.98%;}
.col-7 {width: 58.31%;}
.col-8 {width: 66.64%;}
.col-9 {width: 74.97%;}
.col-10 {width: 83.30%;}
.col-11 {width: 91.63%;}
.col-12 {width: 100%;}


* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: Montserrat;
}

[class*="col-"] {
    float: left;
}

.row:after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.navbar {
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #f27405;
    color: white;
}

.stripemenu {
    padding-left: 1%;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 6px;
}

.menupos {
    padding-top: 7%;
}

.space {
    padding-top: 9px;
}

.icon {
    padding-top: 6px;
}

.iconpos {
    padding-left: 45%;
    position: relative;
}

.share {
    padding-top: 6px;
}
```